# Dealing from a deck of cards (non repeating cards)

Tags: c++, class, pointers

This is a function I have created to try to deal n cards from a deck class of cards. When a card is dealt, it is supposed to be 'removed' from the deck (i.e. can't be dealt again). I thought I solved this by using pointers, and by drawing from the back of the deck minus the amount of cards I have dealt so far. If I call the function again, I need to be drawing from the deck that has cards missing, and since I am not shuffling the deck at any point I thought this method would work.

'dealt' is defined earlier in my code, and starts at 0.
Card is a class that holds a certain suit and value.

I put a sample output of the hands dealt when I call the dealNumber function 6 times and n = 5.

ST CK D3 HJ D9
  HK DK SA SQ DT
  HK S4 D2 C9 H5
  HK H6 H7 H2 H4
  HK HK SK S8 C5
  HK H9 S3 D8 H8

The 'deck' is ordered this way however:

S6 S2 S7 D7 S9 CQ D4 CA CJ SJ HQ DQ D5 HA DA C4 HT H3 CT D6 C2 S5 H8 D8 S3 H9 C7
 C5 S8 SK HK C8 H4 H2 H7 H6 C3 H5 C9 D2 S4 C6 DT SQ SA DK DJ D9 HJ D3 CK ST

The first hand I deal is correct, but the others are not. 'dealt' should be carried over through the deck class regardless, so where am I going wrong?

```
Hand* Deck::dealingNumber(int p){   

Card* dealtCards = new Card[p];
Card* oldDeck = deck;

for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    dealtCards[i] = deck[(51-dealt)-i];
}

dealt = dealt+n;
deck = new Card[52-dealt];

for (int i = 0; i < 51-dealt;i++){
deck[i] = oldDeck[i];
}

delete[] oldDeck;

PokerHand* hand = new PokerHand(dealtCards);

return hand;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong in my code to not be dealing cards correctly.

Comment: Do you have to use arrays for this? Using something like a `std::stack` or a `std::vector` to hold your cards would probably be much easier.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm Here's how to do a shuffle, the Fisher-Yates algorithm. Being able to shuffle is really useful.

Comment: Yes, I need to be using arrays. And I don't need to shuffle the cards, I just need to be dealing from the back of the deck.

Comment: You're making this too complicated. Use `std::deque` with `std::random_shuffle()`. Deal using `pop_back()`.

Comment: can I use pop_back on a dynamically allocated array?

Comment: You have an off-by-one error in your second for loop, it should be `i < 52-dealt` for the condition. I'm not sure if this would cause your problem though.

Comment: `pop_back()` is a member function of `std::vector`, `std::deque`, and `std::list`.

Comment: Actually the off-by-one error fixed it! It's always the simple errors that I overlook.

Comment: Okay, let me write up an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error in your second for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 52 /* change from 51 to 52 */ - dealt; i++){
    deck[i] = oldDeck[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a very different approach using 2 arrays. The first array holds the deck and the second array holds a dealt/not dealt flag.

```
char cards[52][3]; // 52 cards @ 3 characters each
int dealtFlag[52]; // 0=not dealt, 1=dealt
```

Then choose a random number from 0-51, check that dealtFlag[randNum] is zero, and use that card if it is zero. If it is 1, get a new random number and try again.

Comment: This would be very inefficient when dealing the last few cards - for instance, when deciding between the last two cards, only 4% of random numbers would be valid.

Comment: Good point, its efficiency certainly does decrease as cards are dealt out. But if you don't plan on dealing the whole deck then I figure that's not so much of a worry.

Comment: When algorithms that are not broken by design are so easy to code, why pick something with such poor asymptotic behaviour?

Comment: Oh that one's easy: I obviuosly still have LOTS to learn. To be honest, I had no idea that those (much more elegant) solutions even existed. When I learned C++ we were always encouraged (forced?) to build our own solutions. Turns out there's so much more to the language than I was led to believe!

Comment: It's not a property of C++ that there are better solutions, but a property of algorithms in general. More important than picking a fast language or saving a couple of instructions once is picking algorithms that have a good time complexity ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation ), e.g. O(log(n)) instead of O(n), O(n) instead of O(n^2) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this itself is the problem. Anyway this is a problem:
Modify

```
for (int i = 0; i < 51-dealt;i++){
deck[i] = oldDeck[i];
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 52-dealt;i++){
deck[i] = oldDeck[i];
}
```

Using STL classes for your purpose will be much more simpler.
But personally, I would prefer a stack using linked list or similar.